# docker-compose up command hangs on Windows CMD

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am following Essential Angular for ASP.Net Core MVC book and in chapter 4
There is docker file mentioned as below :

```
version: "3"

services:
   database:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest"
    ports:
     - 5100:1433
    environment: 
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=mySecret123
```

and then as per book When I try to run command : **docker-compose up**

the CMD is stuck as below :

[CMD Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcOcN.png)

Couldn't figure out what's issue here ?

Comment: What you want? Just concern about `docker-compose up` not finish? Or you see your `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` output not as expected and hang? Anyway, how you know it hang?

Comment: It looks like your database has started. Now it's just waiting for connections. As long as you do not connect it just does not log anything more.